# How can I get a Color from a list of KeyValuePair?

Tags: c#, colors

I have a Button: btn, and I'm trying to

```
private List<KeyValuePair<String,Color>> myListKeyValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair<String,Color>>

btn.BackColor =  Color.(myListKeyValuePair[i].Value);
```

but it says, 'identificator expected'.

Comment: That's invalid syntax. Can you show the full code / the definition of `myListKeyValuePair`

Comment: private List<KeyValuePair<String,Color>> myListKeyValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair<String,Color>>

Comment: Just use btn.BackColor = myListKeyValuePair[i].Value;

Comment: You haven't used an array here

Comment: @mww Thx, it works. I didn't notice I had btn.BackColor= another color  a few lines after.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a color in the name/value pair, just set the back color to the value.

```
btn.BackColor = myListKeyValuePair[i].Value;
```

Comment: How do you know, `myListKeyValuePair` contains the name?

Comment: I can't be certain it's just a presumption given how he used it.

Comment: @RyanSearle Thx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to retrieve the color from key instead of index (otherwise you'd be interested in just using a **List of type Color**)

```
    //Sample list
    List<KeyValuePair<string, Color>> myListKeyValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Color>>();
    myListKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Color>("Truck", Color.Red));
    myListKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Color>("Car", Color.Green));
    myListKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Color>("Van", Color.Blue));

    //Value retrieve
    Color myDesiredColor = myListKeyValuePair.Where(item => item.Key == "Car").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```